# First odd term of the sequence lower odd number $n$ related to the $3\cdot n+1$ problem

Tags: collatz-conjecture

I have already asked on math.stackexchange if you think the question is off topic I can delete it.

I'm trying to complete the following graph but I'm not sure if I can complete it without getting an infinite number of branches.

I'm looking, if it exists, for an article on the [$\quad 3\cdot n+1 \quad$ problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)  where the first odd terms of the sequence lower than a generic initial odd number $\quad n \quad$ are reported.

Let me explain better I'm trying to build a flowchart  where by making jumps it is possible to go to the next term of the sequence always lower than the previous one.

The original sequence of the $\quad 3\cdot n+1 \quad$ problem with  $ \quad n_0=n \quad $  is as follows:

$n_{i+1}=3\cdot n_i +1 \quad $ if $ \quad n_i \equiv 1\pmod 2 \quad  $

and $n_{i+1}=\frac{n_i}{2}\quad $ if $\quad n_i \equiv 0\pmod 2\quad $

the sequence can be rewritten considering only the odd terms  $\quad n_i \quad $ starting from an odd number $ \quad n$

$n_1=\frac{3 \cdot n +1}{2^{a_1}}$

$n_2=\frac{3 \cdot n_1 +1}{2^{a_2}}=\frac{3 \cdot \frac{3 \cdot n +1}{2^{a_1}} +1}{2^{a_2}}$

$\cdots$

if $\quad k>1$

$n_k=\frac{3 \cdot n_{k-1} +1}{2^{a_k}}=\frac{3^k \cdot n +3^{k-1}+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-2}{\displaystyle3^j\cdot \displaystyle2^{\sum _{i=1} ^{k-1-j} {a_i}}}}{\displaystyle 2^{\sum _{i=1}^{k} {a_i}}}$

using this formula for $\quad n_k\quad$ to find the next odd number less than $\quad n \quad$ it is possible to obtain a pattern given a certain class of numbers modulo $\quad 2^c \quad$ so I started to make the graph

example:

$43 \quad \rightarrow   130 \rightarrow 65 \rightarrow 196 \rightarrow   98 \rightarrow 49  \rightarrow 148  \rightarrow 74  \rightarrow 37\cdots$

the next odd number less than $\quad 43 \quad$ is  $\quad 37=  \frac{27\cdot 43+23}{32}\quad$

the next odd number less than $\quad 107 \quad$ is  $\quad 91=  \frac{27\cdot 107+23}{32}\quad$

the next odd number less than $\quad 171 \quad$ is  $\quad 145=  \frac{27\cdot 171+23}{32}\quad$

$\cdots$

then for the numbers $\quad n\equiv 43 \pmod{64}$ the next odd number is $\quad \frac{27\cdot n+23}{32}$

For each row of the graph the different residue classes are shown modulo $\quad 2^c\quad$ but I have not completed the graph given the long time, I am interested to know if anyone has made a study of this based on the modulo $\quad 2^c\quad$ and in particular if it has studied the first terms of the sequence lower than $\quad n\quad$ in order to be able to verify if for some classes the value of $\quad c\quad$ is too large to get a pattern.

[image]

Edit: I added some branch and I realized that it is not possible to use finite number of branches. Meanwhile I found something related to what I was looking for [OEIS A177789](https://oeis.org/A177789).

Comment: Perhaps the math.stack question was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4649071/considerations-on-the-sequences-of-the-3n-1-problem

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes. and on math.stack I added new formulas to get an indication of how the different branches develop.

Comment: Perhaps it would be more useful if you could -either "accept" some of the answers -or detail more your questions in MSE. ... Or -to make it clear where and why the answers and comment in MSE fail to solve/answer your question so far.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Thanks for the help, I deleted the comment because the link is no longer valid.